# Ethernet network occasionally drops when Wi-FI hotspot is on

Tags: networking, windows-10, ethernet, connection, wifi-configuration

I have a Dell Inspiron 3541 that connects to the Internet with LAN, but uses Wi-Fi hotspot to allow wireless-only devices to connect, too (Dell 1705 Wi-Fi Adapter). When I turn on Wi-Fi hotspot, the LAN disconnects, and flashes "A network change was detected". This was expected, but more errors occur when it is left on that read  `example.com's IP address could not be found.` along with the error code `(DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN)`.

If it helps, my computer uses Cloudflare DNS (1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1), but my wireless devices still use their default (Google DNS, 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4).

How can I fix this (make the Ethernet stop disconnecting to the computer when Wi-Fi hotspot is on)?

Answer (score 0):

Sound to me like when you swap to the wifi hotspot it has to perform DNS flush and renew since you are changing DNS servers.

Try setting the DNS of both to be the same address.